# Register C functions of the same signatures in Lua

Tags: c, lua

Suppose we have many C functions of the same signatures and we want to register them to Lua. For example, each function looks like this one:

```
void foo(int n)
{
   // do some work
}
```

We can register each of them with:

```
int wrap_foo(Lua_State *l)
{
   int x = lua_tonumber(l, 1);
   foo(x);
   return 0;
}

lua_pushcfunction(l, wrap_foo);
lua_setglobal(l, "foo");
```

The question is: How to implement the following function to avoid repetitive code.

```
void register(Lua_State *l, const char *name, void (*f)(int));
```

Possibly, one can do it with a preprocessor macro (compile-time only). Is there a more elegant way? I would prefer a solution without any external binding libraries.

Comment: You could have just the one wrapper function, and then store the correct function pointer in an [upvalue](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html) each time you register it. Then in the function, just read the upvalue and call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couldn't name it `register`, because that's a keyword, but if we called it, say, `register_wrapper`, we can implement James McLaughlin's suggestion like this:

```
// wrapper for a C function taking a single number argument
// the C function is bound to this wrapper as an upvalue
int wrapper(lua_State *L)
{
    int x = lua_tonumber(L,1);
    void (*wrapped)(int) = (void (*)(int)) lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    wrapped(x);
    return 0;
}

// bind a C function to our wrapper function
void register_wrapper(lua_State* L, const char* name, void(*wrapped)(int))
{
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, wrapped);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, wrapper, 1);
    lua_setglobal(L, name);
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    register_wrapper(L, "foo", foo);
    register_wrapper(L, "bar", bar);
    ...
```